# log or restrict the source user of ssh login

Tags: ssh, login, sshd

Is it possible to log and/or restrict the source user of an ssh login?

**For example:**

`user1@server1` logs into `server2` as `user2` .

also, `user3@server1` logs into `server2` as `user2` .

By "source user" I mean `user1` or `user3` above.

I would like to be able to track which session was initiated by `user1@server1` and which session was initiated by `user3@server1`.

The purpose for this is multiple users may be using the `user2` account to e.g. manage processes on server2. (I realize there are security implications of this but part of this question is assessing the extent of those).

As mentioned in the man page of `sshd_config(5)`, `sshd` is capable of restricting access to a particular user using the `AllowUsers` config option in `sshd_config`.

> AllowUsers
>
> This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by
>       spaces. If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not
>       recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users. If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts. The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroup, and finally AllowGroups.

But the `USER` specified in the above man page seems to be describing the username on the TARGET machine (`server2` in the example).

I tested this by setting the AllowUsers option to `user2@server1` , and found I was still able to login from `user1@server1` -> `user2@server2`.

Also, the log does not seem to show any source user.

This is the log `/var/log/secure` on RHEL6, after logging in from `user1@server1` -> `user2@server2`

> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: Connection from 10.1.2.3 port 36508
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: Found matching RSA key: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:..
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28350]: Postponed publickey for user2 from 10.1.2.3 port 36508 ssh2
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: Found matching RSA key: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:..
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: Accepted publickey for user2 from 10.1.2.3 port 36508 ssh2
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user2 by (uid=0)
>
> Nov 17 16:14:59 server2 sshd[28349]: User child is on pid 28351

So, is there any way to

(a) change the logging or behavior of `sshd` so that it will track the source user making the ssh connection?

(b) restrict sshd to restrict connections based on the source user?

Comment: Are the logins to server2 (as user2) being done with passwords or public keys? If the latter then look at the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` and see if `command` or `environment` might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, the server will accept any valid login from the server side perspective.

There are however some possible workarounds to achieve what you want. Test and see if the following will suit your needs.

**Note** that this might be sufficient for 'average' users and requires that you also control the clients. Experienced users will find a way to forge the `CLIENTUSER` variable used below.

By using the `AcceptEnv` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you can accept for instance a variable called CLIENTUSER:

```
AcceptEnv CLIENTUSER
```

Next step is to force the users login command to a login shell like:

```
ForceCommand /bin/bash -l
```

Restart your sshd service and add the following to /etc/profile

```
if [ -z "$CLIENTUSER" ] || [ "$CLIENTUSER" != "user3" ] && [ ! -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]
then
       echo 'Client logon not allowed'
       logout
fi
```

The above will logout every client who does not send the `CLIENTUSER` variable or sending the `CLIENTUSER` variable with another value than `user3`.

You can test this using the following client commandline:

```
$ ssh user2@host
Client logon not allowed

$ CLIENTUSER=user3 ssh -o "SendEnv CLIENTUSER" user2@host
user2@host $
```

As you can see the `CLIENTUSER` can easily be forged from the commandline. To prevent this you can add the following to the *client* `/etc/profile:

```
declare -r CLIENTUSER="$USER"
```

When the user tries to change the value of the `CLIENTUSER` variable he/she will receive the following error:

```
bash: CLIENTUSER: readonly variable
```

Comment: +1 especially for the short answer of no. I see what you mean for using the environment variables, though I got around the readonly variable by just using `ksh` or a new `bash` instance after the initial login on the source machine `server1`.

Comment: @hilcharge, you are right. Therefore I've put the note above the workaround.